# Ruby 'next' statement within a 'while' loop

Tags: ruby, loops, cucumber

I'm trying to write a test that performs a while loop that will eventually be responsible for iterating through 1920 loops spread across several scenarios.

In the event of one loop failing, in this case, the text doesn't match, I'd like the loop to move to the next iteration.

Here is my while loop that iterates correctly:

```
And(/^click on the endorsement to confirm court description from rows "(.*?)" to "(.*?)"$/) do |first_row, last_row|


data = CsvMapper.import('C:/auto_test_data/Courts code example csv.csv') do
    [dln, ni, pc, endorse, courtdesc]
  end


    cell = first_row.to_i - 1

while cell < last_row.to_i

  endorsement = data.at(cell).endorse
  courtdescription = data.at(cell).courtdesc

  find('li.category', text: endorsement).click

  court = first('li.offence-court', text: 'Court/Fixed penalty office')


  expect(court).to have_text courtdescription
  # add 'next' statement if this step fails

find('li.category', text: endorsement).click

cell = cell + 1


puts court.text



 end
  end
```

In that loop, I've commented where the point of failure will be and need something that will cause the loop to move to the next iteration.

Error handling is optional at this point.

Any help on this would be great as I'd prefer not to go down the route of Example tables in Cucumber for 1920 iterations.

Thanks

Comment: If you do that, your test will never fail. What's the point?

Comment: Could we add an exception and log it to identify which iterations had failed in the loop? That's the end goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preventing the assertion from failing your test is a weird way to go, and if you have multiple things you want to report from one test, it's a sign you should perhaps have multiple tests. But sticking with this strategy, it would work reasonably well to build up a set of mismatched data and then assert when you're finished that it's empty. Then your test fails in the right cases, and you have a list of which iterations caused it.

```
failures = []
while cell < last_row.to_i
  # Gather your data
  failures << [cell, court] unless court.text.include?(courtdescription)
  # Prepare for the next iteration
end
expect(failures).to be_empty
```

Comment: I agree. The purpose of the test is that ALL of the data will pass the test; that's how you know that the test worked. The framework is meant to fail when a failure occurs, so that the failure can be fixed.

Comment: Ye, I understand that.  But this while loop will handle 1940 rows within the csv (business requirement, tried to push back) so if one iteration out of the 1940 fails, we'd like to raise an exception of some sort to highlight the failure and then carry on to the next iteration of the while loop. Instead of it failing at say line 10 and leaving a potential 1930 untested.  By having one row at a time in the example table format, it takes on average 8 hours to run.  Calculations show this approach will take 52 minutes